# keep colors of multiple lines chart created from a 2d numpy array while doing gif animation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to get this 2d numpy array into a plot as multiple lines chart.

```
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

The code works, it is just that the colors are changing for each frame of the gif. Each column should get and keep one color for each frame. Is there a smarter way to label the lines so I get random colors?

```
import gif
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, animation
ims = []
gif.options.matplotlib["dpi"] = 100
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for i in rage (0,5):
    ...    
    lines = axs[1, 0].plot(data) #data is changing based on i let's say
    ...
    final_ims = [im1, im2, im4, text1, text2, text3]
    final_ims.extend(lines)
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, final_ims, interval=200, blit=True,
                                                repeat_delay=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a code that plots 4 lines with random colors.
If u want, u can uncomment random.seed(60) to fix the color.

I didn't fully undestand your question, but i cant write comments (but can write for my answer), so i will post the code as i understand. In comments under i will try to answer your questions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,3,4,5,6,7]])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

# List of random colors
colors = []
# To fix colors
#random.seed(60)

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    # Add RGB color with use of tuples ()
        colors.append((random.random(), random.random(), random.random()))

# Plot all lines
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        axs[i, j].plot(data[i * 2 + j], color=colors[i * 2 + j])

plt.show()
```